Firebase hosting doesn't deploy files
I was trying to deploy a basic webpage with only HTML, CSS, JS and a couple of images, I had done this process at least 5 times before but this time it didn't work. When I deployed the deployment didn't show any error, nor the logs, and even when I ran the command Firebase serve, it worked just fine, but when deployed nothing worked, the HTML was displayed but no CSS, no JS and no images. The console showed errors like "Unexpected token '<'" but the answers from Stack Overflow or any other page didn't work, I inspected the page and check the sources and some of my CSS and JS files weren't there and the ones that were had the HTML, from my index HTML code, in them. I even copy the files of my new project and pasted them in an old project that was running fine, it didn't work, after that I reverted the changes, deployed the old files in the old project and now this one didn't work.

I contacted Firebase support and the first time based on the "Unexpected token '<'" they told me that it was a developer mistake. The second time I contacted Firebase support, after I had triple checked everything, They told me that maybe I was using an old version of Firebase CLI, I updated my Firebase CLI, and it works now, both projects, my new one and the old one that stopped working.
